# Pycharm flask route breake point not working

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

Breakpoint never reached for breakpoint.

```
def new():
    try:
        db = get_db()
        cur = db.cursor()
        group_list = cur.execute('select name,count(name) from ac_group group by name').fetchall()         
    except sqlite3.Error as err:
        print(err)

    return render_template('group/newgroup.html', group_list=group_list)
```

I want to know what is in the list before it passes to the route.

Comment: I think the question is poorly composed. At least to me, the context isn't clear, as well as what exactly you expect, what you tried, why that failed, and where exactly you got stuck. If you need some guidelines on how to ask, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you improve the question, you're more likely to get help, and to get it faster!

Comment: Where is the breakpoint? What list? What is the expected behavior and what happens instead?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I got it

I just shutdown the system and restarted and the debugging on root really working

Some time issue with pycharm